# Difference between two queries in SQL (Oracle Apex Items)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, apex

I have the two following queries in different items in an APEX application:

---

ITEM 1:

```
SELECT SUM(t.gems)
  FROM (SELECT gems
          FROM tasks
         UNION ALL
        SELECT gems
          FROM quests
         UNION ALL
        SELECT gems
          FROM daily_quests
         ) t
```

---

ITEM 2:

```
SELECT SUM(price) FROM items
```

---

They both return a number correctly, but I want to subtract them in one statement. I tried to use

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(ITEM1)-TO_NUMBER(ITEM2) FROM DUAL
```

but it didn't work.

Do you have any suggestions? I am a bit new to APEX and SQL.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Cross joins both queries; then you can access both values and substract them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a CTE (Common table expression) for each of the queries, then `CROSS JOIN` them.

```
WITH t_gems (sum_gems) AS
(
SELECT SUM(t.gems)
  FROM (SELECT gems
          FROM tasks
         UNION ALL
        SELECT gems
          FROM quests
         UNION ALL
        SELECT gems
          FROM daily_quests
         ) t
), t_items (sum_price) AS
(
  SELECT SUM(price) FROM items
)
SELECT t_gems.sum_gems - t_item.sum_price 
  FROM t_gems CROSS JOIN t_items
```

Comment: It is sufficient to use a single subquery: union `select -price from items` and aggregate the results

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each query produces a column named `gems` you can do:

```
with
a as (
  -- query 1 here
),
b as (
  -- query 2 here
)
select a.gems - b.gems as diff
from a
cross join b
```

Comment: Thank you, but it is not working here.

Comment: Please provide a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Koen's answer gives the general, correct answer for this type of problem.

In your particular instance, however, you can use a simpler query:

```
SELECT SUM(t.gems)
FROM (SELECT gems FROM tasks
      UNION ALL
      SELECT gems FROM quests
      UNION ALL
      SELECT gems FROM daily_quests
      UNION ALL
      SELECT price * -1 FROM items
) t
```